# Возможно ли проигнорировать hover эффекты при движении курсора?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Хотелось бы сделать меню как на браузерах Opera или Chrome. Возникает вопрос : Возможно ли проигнорировать hover эффекты при движении курсора?

Ссылка на текущий вид (первая секция меню): 
  http://osiyo-nur.uz/goodgross/

Использовал такой Jquery код:
          $('.r_div').fadeToggle(50).delay(1500);

Comment: покажи свой пример, выложи сюда, что можно было иметь представления о чем идет речь

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно сделать задержку на некоторое время с помощью css:

```
transition: transform 1s step-end;
```

Но такой прием применяется, если у вас анимация не плавная при наведении.
Если же необходимо сделать плавную, то, я думаю, придется делать через js с помощью `stop()`, `delay(1000)` и `.animate({"marginLeft":"10px"},'2500')`.